# Replace values in an array to a RGB values (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the below code to replace a value in an array to a certain value

The value which are >0.5 are replaced with 1.12

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([
[0.42436315, 0.48558583, 0.32924763], 
[0.2439979,0.58220701,0.38213418], 
[0.5097581,0.34528799,0.1563123]
])
print("Original array:")
print(x)
print("Replace all elements of the said array with 1.12 which are greater than .5")
x[x > .5] = 1.12
print(x)
```

Instead of replacing it with a number, I need to replace it with an RGB value like [0, 255, 255]

The values which are >0.5 has to be replaced with  [0, 255, 255]

It is giving me an error, when am trying to save it with an RGB value.

Any idea on this is much more helpful

Comment: Can you explain what you tried to do and what errors you get with the codes? When you say when the values are greater than 0.5, does that mean all the values on the a row, or any single value in a row?

Comment: And also what the expected output would be. From your description it looks like you want to replace a single value with an array (thus changing the structure) of the `x`.

Comment: Try 1: String conversion error to float Try 2: Arguments doesn't match. I just tried to assign an RGB value in place of 1.12

Comment: @Matt, I will replace all the values in my array to RGB values. The structure will be same

Comment: Let's say your array contains 3 RGB pixels, correct? So its shape is (3,3). Now we start replacing, so we come to the central value of `0.58220701` and we want to replace it, so we remove that ONE value and write in your THREE new RGB values. The structure is no longer the same because there are now 5 values in the middle row, not 3.

Comment: So where `x>.5` is `[0,255,255]` and the other places are still float? TYou do know that heterogeneous data is discourage in numpy right?